# How can I parse many files at the same time with one line commands(Linux/Unix)

Tags: linux, awk, cat

There are many logs files I need to parse, and below is the sample structures.
I need to view debug.log files contents under each directory at the same time with one line of commands(Linux/Unix). Probably with awk/sed/cat etc.
The number of directories(1,2,3,4...) vary. I need to limit the directory with names instead of '*'.

```
1/logs/debug.log
2/logs/debug.log
3/logs/debug.log
4/logs/debug.log
5/logs/debug.log
6/logs/debug.log
```

If each debug.log contents are below:

```
In 1/logs/debug.log: finished. 
               Please go ahead next step.     
In 2/logs/debug.log: failed.      
In 3/logs/debug.log: finished. 
               Please go ahead next step.     
In 4/logs/debug.log: finished. 
               Please go ahead next step.     
In 5/logs/debug.log: Error.       
In 6/logs/debug.log: finished. 
               Please go ahead next step.
```

Expected outputs:

```
1: finished. 
1: Please go ahead next step.     
2: failed.    
3: finished. 
3: Please go ahead next step.     
4: finished. 
4: Please go ahead next step.     
5: Error.     
6: finished. 
6: Please go ahead next step.
```

Sorry for very complex question but would be appreciated if you could let me know the direction to the solution.

## I got an Answer

Need to use 'Loop' to traverse all sub directories.

Comment: We aren't here to do all the work for you. We can help *you* write the code but not just do it all. At least try something, show what you have tried and then explain exactly what it is that is preventing you from progressing.

Comment: Sorry but sometimes there is the time we can't think of anything for our issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS=': ' 'FNR==1{dir=FILENAME; sub("/.*","",dir)} {print dir, $0}' */logs/debug.log
```

Comment: What if I need to limit some directories instead of '*'? I thought I can put the name of directory I need to parse with a loop style in 'for' clause. Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to provide more concrete information in a question, including concise, testable sample input and expected output, for us to be able to advise you on whatever it is you're asking how to do.